# Color plotly text annotation

Tags: r, annotations, plotly, scatter

I have clustered `xy` data which I'd like to plot using `R`'s `plotly` where the points are colored by their cluster membership and there's text annotating the cluster number and the fraction of the points out of the total. I'm also trying to get this text annotation to be in the same colors as the points, i.e., colored by cluster.

Here's my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(1,20,4),function(i) data.frame(x=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),y=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),cluster=i)))
df$cluster <- factor(df$cluster)
cluster.colors <- c("#FF6C91","#EF7F47","#D39300","#AAA300","#6BB100")
cluster.centers.df <- dplyr::group_by(df,cluster) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(x=mean(x),y=mean(y),n=n()) %>% unique()
cluster.centers.df$percentage <- cluster.centers.df$n/sum(cluster.centers.df$n)
cluster.centers.df$cluster <- as.character(cluster.centers.df$cluster)


plot_ly(marker=list(size=12),type='scatter',mode="markers",x=df$x,y=df$y,color=df$cluster,colors=cluster.colors,showlegend=F) %>%
  add_annotations(text=sprintf("<b>%s</b>",paste0(cluster.centers.df$cluster,"\n",gsub("\\.00","",as.character(cluster.centers.df$percentage)),"%")),showarrow=T,arrowhead=1,arrowsize=1,x=cluster.centers.df$x,y=cluster.centers.df$y,ax=20,ay=-30,font=list(size=14,color=cluster.colors)) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F),yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F))
```

This, however, does not color the text according to `cluster.colors`.

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to figure out why `add_annotations()` method didn't work, so I created the annotations manually and added the colors on each for loop iteration. Please refer the below code and let me know if this fixes your issue.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(1,20,4),function(i) data.frame(x=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),y=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),cluster=i)))
df$cluster <- factor(df$cluster)
cluster.colors <- c("#FF6C91","#EF7F47","#D39300","#AAA300","#6BB100")
cluster.centers.df <- dplyr::group_by(df,cluster) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(x=mean(x),y=mean(y),n=n()) %>% unique()
cluster.centers.df$percentage <- cluster.centers.df$n/sum(cluster.centers.df$n)
cluster.centers.df$cluster <- as.character(cluster.centers.df$cluster)

a <- c()
for (i in 1:length(cluster.centers.df$cluster)){
  a[[i]] <- list(text=sprintf("<b>%s</b>",paste0(cluster.centers.df$cluster[i],"\n",gsub("\\.00","",as.character(cluster.centers.df$percentage[i])),"%")),showarrow=T,arrowhead=1,arrowsize=1,x=cluster.centers.df$x[i],y=cluster.centers.df$y[i],ax=20,ay=-30,font=list(size=14,color=cluster.colors[i]))
}
plot_ly(marker=list(size=12),type='scatter',mode="markers",x=df$x,y=df$y,color=df$cluster,colors=cluster.colors,showlegend=F) %>%
layout(annotations = a, xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F),yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F))
```